# Countering circular reference with SUM and OFFSET (VLOOKUP & VBA involved)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

To give you a breakdown of my spreadsheet:

I have a master spreadsheet that pulls data from another spreadsheet (generated daily), placing it into the next empty column and converting the column that previously held the formula to values. This is achieved with a combination of the following formula and VBA code:

`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP("Row 1",'N:\Reports\[data.xls]Sheet1'!$A$2:$B$40,2,FALSE)),0,(VLOOKUP("Row 1",'N:\Reports\[data.xls]Sheet1'!$A$2:$B$40,2,FALSE)))`

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim rLastCell As Range
Dim LastCol As Integer

Set rLastCell = ws.Cells.Find(what:="*", After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

LastCol = rLastCell.Column

ws.Columns(LastCol).Copy ws.Columns(LastCol + 1)

With ws.Columns(LastCol)
.Copy .Offset(0, 1)
.Value = .Value
End With

End Sub
```

The intention is for Column B to be a 'totals' column, that dynamically sums all of the values in the relevant row as new entries are pulled by the formula/VBA combo and added to the first blank column. Unfortunately though, I also need to subtract that row's total from the value that the formula returns--however, doing so creates a circular reference.

My solution was to just exclude the last cell in the row (that has the formula) from the total, with this:

`=SUM(C2:OFFSET(I$2,0,-1))`

However, the dynamic range doesn't appear all that dynamic. It doesn't expand to include the next column when a new record is added, and I'm really not enough of a hand at this stuff to figure out why or how to rectify it.

Thanks in advance for any assistance with this and please don't hesitate to ask for any clarification!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use =SUM(C2:IV2)?

Comment: Sorry, I should explain a bit better - the data pulled from the other spreadsheet is a month-to-date figure, so it compounds daily. Because I only want the daily figure, to achieve that, I need to subtract that number by the total of the previous days. If that total was fetched by =SUM(C2:IV2), it would include the figure from the cell that I'm subtracting from in the formula, which then creates a circular reference. This is what I'm trying to get around.

Answer (score 0):

It may be simplest to use a named range. If you name the column before the monthly total say LastDay, you can use:

```
=SUM(C2:INDEX(LastDay,ROW())
```

as your formula, and your code then becomes:

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim rLastCell As Range
Dim LastCol As Integer

Set rLastCell = ws.Cells.Find(what:="*", After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

LastCol = rLastCell.Column

With ws.Columns(LastCol)
.Copy .Offset(0, 1)
.Value = .Value
.Name = "LastDay"
End With

End Sub
```

Assuming I have understood your layout correctly.